# includegraphics tabular

Tags: tables, align

I need to include some pictures in a tabular.
The problem is that the text is aligned to the bottom then.

```
\begin{tabular}{c|p{3cm}|c|c|}

 A & B & C & D \\
 \toprule
 Content & More Content & More Content  &
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{bla.PNG}\\
```

How can I set the text align to the middle of the col?

Tank you in advance

Comment: Welcome, i doubt that your tabular will work the way you have posted it. Can you please provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|p{3cm}|c|c|}
A & B & C & D \\\toprule
Content & More Content & More Content  & \adjincludegraphics[valign=M,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and not use vertical lines :-) . If they the should be present, than is better to use ``hline` instead rules form `booktabs` and to `includegraphics` option add: `margin=0pt 2ex`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to include the image in a `\parbox`

```
\parbox[c]{0.7\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{bla.png}}
```